# Not able to set height of paragraph in percentage

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem:
HTML:

```
<div id="picture_buttons">
            <p class="images"></p>
            <p class="images"></p>
            <p class="images"></p>
            <p class="images"></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#picture_buttons{
    width:74%;
    margin:20px auto 20px auto;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:2%;
    border:solid 1px white;
    text-align:center;
}
.images{
    width:34%;
    height:45%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:6%;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Now I am facing two problems: First, I am not able to set the height of paragraphs in %. It just doesn't display anything, but if I specify the size in pixels, then there is no problem. Second, the `text-align:center;` property in "#picture_buttons" is not working as well.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the percentage height, you need to specify the height of parent elements.

Try this:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#picture-buttons { height: 100%; }
```

For an explanation of how percentage height works, see my answer here:
[Why is the 'height' property with percentage value not working on my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

Comment: the container element is the div, not the whole webpage.

Comment: Okay let me post a picture

Comment: This is your code, with my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/0zthsv5a/ (I added border and color for demo purposes.)

Comment: your code is perfect! But, if I don't want the height of the div to be 100%, then?(Consider it is 75%)

Comment: Yeah, you can change those numbers however you wish. The point is you need to specify a height on parent containers when you use percentage heights on the child. For the reasoning behind this read my other answer, which I posted in the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks a ton! But my final question: If we have specified the height of the body, then why specify the height of html?

Comment: My friend, it will all be quickly explained if you read my other answer, which is short and sweet. Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0zthsv5a/1/

Comment: And @Michael_B, why is the `text-align:center;` property not working?

Comment: remove the `float: left`